# How can I model this code in promela/SP?

Tags: spin, promela

The following algorithm attempts to enforce mutual exclusion
between two processes P1 and P2 each of which runs the code below.
You can assume that initially sema = 0.

```
while true do{
atomic{if sema = 0
then sema:= 1
else
 go to line 2}
critical section;
sema:= 0;
  }
```

How Can I model this code in promela/SPIN?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be quite straightforward:

```
active proctype P() {
  bit sema = 0;

  do
    :: atomic {
         sema == 0 -> sema = 1
       }

       // critical section

       sema = 0
  od
}
```

Possibly you do not need the `do` loop, if in your code you only needed it for some active waiting. The atomic block is only executable if `sema` is set to 0, and then it executes at once. Spin has a built-in passive waiting semantics.